# Why am I getting an application error when I upload my Postgres database to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, heroku, deployment

I created a database only application on Heroku using Postgres and tried to connect to it using NodeJS. It has a table named meetings. I have no issues connecting to and interacting with the Heroku database from the command line, but when I go to the domain, I get an "Application error" message.
When I type "heroku logs --tail" in the command line to check what's wrong, I get the message:

> at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=app-name.herokuapp.com request_id=************* fwd="********" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https

Below is the content of my index.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const pool = require("./database");

//middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json()); // => allows us to access the req.body

//ROUTES//

//get all Meetings

app.get("/meetings", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const allMeetings = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM meetings");

        res.json(allMeetings.rows);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
});

//get a meeting

app.get("/meetings/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { meeting_id } = req.params;
        const meeting = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM meetings WHERE * = $1`, [
            meeting_id,
        ]);
        res.json(meeting.rows[0]);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
});

//create a meeting

app.post("/meetings", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body);
        const { meeting_date, meeting_time, title, client, meeting_address, objective } = req.body;
        const newMeeting = await pool.query(
            `INSERT INTO meetings(meeting_id, meeting_date, meeting_time, title, client, meeting_address, objective) VALUES(uuid_generate_v4(), date $1, time $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING * `,
            [meeting_date, meeting_time, title, client, meeting_address, objective]
        );

        res.json(newMeeting.rows[0]);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
});

//update a meeting

app.put("/meetings/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params;
        const { title } = req.body;
        const updateMeeting = await pool.query(
            "UPDATE meetings SET title = $1 WHERE meeting_id = $2",
            [title, id]
        );

        res.json("Meeting was updated");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
});

//delete a meeting

app.delete("/meetings/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { meeting_id } = req.params;
        const deleteMeeting = await pool.query("DELETE FROM meetings WHERE meeting_id = $1", [
            meeting_id,
        ]);
        res.json("Meeting was deleted");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
});

app.listen(5432, () => {
    console.log(`Server is starting on port 5432`);
});
```

Why can't I access the database from the domain like an API?

Comment: seems you didn't deploy the application: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h81-blank-app

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis but it entered "git add .", then "git commit -m "comment", then "git push heroku master

Comment: And what happened when you did that? You should get a whole bunch of output. Were there errors? Did the application fail to deploy? Are you sure you're looking at the same app you deployed to?